# Only one value in file, numpy.loadtxt() just returns the value instead of array?

Tags: python, numpy

When only one value in file, numpy.loadtxt() just returns the value instead of array, how to avoid?

Thank you in advance!

e.g. there's only 12345 in a file

```
12345.6
```

numpy.loadtxt() returns

```
12345.6
```

instead of

```
array([12345.6])
```

Comment: Please show your code, the input and the read result.

Comment: @MikeMüller updated, I thought you could understand my english..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `ndmin` parameter of `numpy.loadtxt`.  Set it to 1, and you will always have an array with at least one dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ndmin=1`:

```
numpy.loadtxt(fobj, ndmin=1)
```

to get a 1D array.